# How to rotate a sprite along a circular path?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

[image: (Click here for the sprite image)]

This is a wheel I have consisting of four individual sprites. My aim is to rotate them as a wheel. I have tried 'UIBezier' arccenter class but the end result is the individual sprite moving along the center but rotating its shape too, leading to an unwanted result. Here is the relavant code. the 'orientToPath' when set to true, rotates the sprite itself.

```
//path rotation
let dx = whlPurple.position.x - self.size.width/2
let dy = whlPurple.position.y - (whlRed.size.height/2 + (whlPurple.position.y - whlRed.size.height))
let rad = atan2(dy, dx)
let radius = sqrt((dx*dx) + (dy*dy))
let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: (whlRed.size.height/2 + (whlPurple.position.y - whlRed.size.height))), radius: radius, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 6), clockwise: true)

let follow = SKAction.follow(path.cgPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)

whlPurple.run(SKAction.repeatForever(follow))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an SKNode and place it at the center of your circle.

Then add your sprite to it (addChild) at a position of CGPoint(x:radius,y:0). you can set the zRotation of the SKNode to chose your starting position on the circle.

When you rotate the SKNode, your sprite will move in a perfect circle.  For example, to have the spites go around in 5 seconds, you can use SKAction.rotate(by: 2*pi, duration:5) and repeat that forever (on the SKNode containing the sprite (not on the sprite itself).